# Get videos specific to a user from search result

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the Google.Apis.Youtube.v3 plugin in .NET MVC.

```
var service = _youTubeService.GetYouTubeService;
var searchReq = service.Search.List("snippet");
searchReq.ChannelId = "exampleIdGoesHere"; // search this channel
searchReq.Q = "acoustic"; // search term

var model = new YouTubeViewModel {
    Data = searchReq.Execute().Items
}

return View(model);
```

In my view, my goal is to embed the videos. But so far, the only relevant information I can get are the search result's title and description. The items, each being a `SearchResult` object, is not exactly a `Video` - which I'm looking for.

Two questions:
- How do you retrieve videos that are from a specific user only (using the .NET plugin)?
- How do you get the video information such as URL, for embedding purposes?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

Comment: @L.B Hi! yes I've been on the API site for quite some time, but I just haven't found a way for the plugin to work the way I wanted it to. It seems incomplete at this point

Answer (score 0):

To get all videos for a specific channel using v3 you'll need to to do the following steps.

1. Get the channel uploads Playlist Id.  You get get this using the [Channels list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) call
2. Then get a list of videos in the uploads playlist using the [playlistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) call

From there you can create the video url using the "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video.Id

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I was looking for videos of a particular user instead of channel. =)